# Ideal CSV-structure for multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I need to export a huge php multidimensional array containing the following structure:

```
[0]
    ['id'] => 0
    ['items']
        [0] => "ItemA"
        [1] => "ItemB"
    ['vars']
        [0]
            [0] => "blue"
            [1] => "green"
            [2] => "red"
        [1]
            [0] => "happy"
            [1] => "sad"
        [2]
            [0] => "old"
[1]
    ['id'] => 1
    ['items']
        [0] => "ItemX"
    ['vars']
        [0]
            [0] => "orange"
            [1] => "pink"
        [1]
            [0] => "bitter"
        [2]
            [0] => "new"
            [1] => "modern"
```

...and so on. 
As you see, the sizes of the sub-arrays are not always the same ( [0]['items'] = 2 vs. [1]['items'] = 1).

I need to write an .CSV-File which later will be read by a JavaScript-function, which should reassemble the original structure.

What should a record in the .CSV-File look like to enable this and make it as easy as possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be a CSV? This sounds like a job for a relational database model.

Comment: CSV's arent multidimensional.  So you'll have to do some string trickery.

Comment: CSV is far from the best way to represent such a structure; it can't, really, and it'll require some sort of convention on top of basic CSV syntax.  JSON or XML would be much, much better. I guess you could create a CSV file with one line and one cell, such that the cell contains the JSON representation of the entire thing :-)

Comment: Seems to be more like JSON to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [JSON](http://json.org) which perfectly fits such requirements. Representing nested data with CSV would be madness (as already pointed out in some of the comments).
In PHP you can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode the data as JSON and to decode it, use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). As the name suggests it *(JavaScript Object Notation)* JavaScript is perfectly fit to handle JSON formatted data.

Answer (score 1):

Simple JSON:

```
[
  {"id": 0, "items": ["ItemA", "ItemB"], "vars": : [["blue", "green", "red"], ["happy", "sad"], ["old"]]},
  {"id": 1, "items": ["ItemX"], "vars": : [["orange", "pink"], ["bitter"], ["new", "modern"]]}
]
```

This will be read just as is by Javascript and become a Javascript array of objects.

Comment: And since the question is tagged with PHP, he already should have `json_encode()` available